# Change headers automatically

Tags: header-footer

Is it possible to use one header for the first page and another one for the following pages? If so, how can I do it automatically, without using the `\thispagestyle{___}` command?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In your preamble, use `\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{...}}`... that's somewhat automatic, since you're separating the content from the setup. Perhaps you could describe what you consider to be automatic or not, and or how you plan on using this requirement.

Comment: The first page of chapters uses pagestyle `plain`. You can redefine it in various ways, a solution depends on your basic setup, so a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed here. As you can tell by comparing my comment to the answer, your question is unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a standard class, and use the `\maketitle`-command to create a title on the first page, this happens automatically. Just put `\pagestyle{headings}` in the preamble, and `\maketitle` after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
% \AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}} % uncomment this line if you do not 
                                          % use `\maketitle`
\begin{document}
\title{An Important Agreement}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
%% Remove the three lines above if you do not use `\maketitle` to set a title.

Text

\newpage

Text
\end{document}
```

If you do not use `maketitle`, just put

```
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

in the preamble, most logically after the `\pagestyle-command

I interpreted your question that you wanted to avoid `\thispagestyle`in the text. If you need a more advance advance solution, you have to write a macro, testing for page 1 and page 2 and set the correct pagestyle. Please describe what you are aiming for.

If you want to get rid of the commands in the preamble, you have to write your own class file, or a package (.sty-file).